# Why ctypes misses ptrdiff_t?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, ctypes

I'm puzzled by the absence of `ptrdiff_t` type in `ctypes`.

Out of 3 types defined in `stddef.h`, `wchar_t` and `size_t` are present in `ctypes`. But not `ptrdiff_t`.

I've been working with Fortran's iso_c_binding, and there my expectation nicely matches with the fact that it does [define](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ISO_005fC_005fBINDING.html) `C_PTRDIFF_T` since 2008.

So I'm thinking about Python in the same terms: how Python is supposed to be C-compatible, if it misses a well-standardized type definition?

Comment: What would having `ptrdiff_t` let you do that you can't do right now?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans it will allow me to provide Python bindings to a C function which uses `ptrdiff_t` for its arguments or return value, explicitly or as a part of structure or union.

Comment: I'm struggling to think of an API where it would make sense to pass a pointer difference as argument (as opposed to the library itself using them internally). Do you have a concrete example of where this would make sense? Libraries generally don't need you to do their internal memory layout work for them.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans , the question is not about creating an API, but about ctypes to provide an ability to call _any_ C function from Python. For example, dav1d library has a public C header that makes use of ptrdiff_t.  I sincerely think that discussing whether it is a good API or not does not belong to this question. It's just a matter of fact (not taste) that C interfacing should be supported by Python in full.

Comment: `ctypes` is for using C/C++ compiled libraries in Python, though, so it's not about "creating" an API but "interfacing with" an API that you load from .so/.dll, and for there's just... no need for a pointer type on the Python side or library function calls?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, clearly there is a need to interact with pointers on the Python side. Please consider for example how NumPy must deploy the underlying BLAS routines that take a lot of pointer arguments.

Comment: `ctypes` has `c_ssize_t` which is basically the same thing.  Alias it as `ptrdiff_t = ctypes.c_ssize_t` if you must.

Comment: Gentlemen, I see there is `ptrdiff_t` in cython: https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/tests/run/ptrdiff_t.pyx So the question becomes how to access it.

Comment: I really don't understand why Cython is relevant here. Ctypes and Cython are unrelated.

Comment: @DavidW Yes, but example of Cython is relevant in the sense that it proves that my request for `ptrdiff_t` in ctypes is legitmate, because Cython has it.

Comment: Have you considered directing your request to [the people that actually maintain ctypes](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues)?

Comment: @DavidW, yes, that's the next thing I'll do.